# How to create a custom property for SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

For example I am trying to make some SKSpriteNode, and they can only last for 10 secs. I want to create a custom property called "bornTime" for the node, so that in update() if `currentTime - bornTime > 10`, the node will be removed.

Comment: you can assign a nsmutabledictionary to userData, to store any custom properties. that way you needn't subclass the node

Answer (score 5):

You need to subclass an SKSpriteNode to a custom Object. In there you can set the properties that you wish:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class mySpriteNode: SKSpriteNode {
       
    let bornTime = NSDate()
}
```

Then, you can compare that date with current date and see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking to do tensions for SKSpriteNode. Your solution is much better and easy!

Comment: i would change NSDate into CACurrentMediaTime.  currentTime is a CFTimeInterval, you cant easily do comparisons between that and an NSDate (as far as I know).. Easier to use CACurrentMediaTime which is also a CFTimeInterval

Comment: @hamobi I agree. I was searching for the absolute time method but I don't remember it exactly. There's also time interval since 1970 that is expressed in seconds so no conversion needed if I'm not mistaken..

Answer (score 2):

an alternative way to do this would be to add an SKAction with an delay to the node which would remove itself from the parent node:

```
        mynode.run(SKAction.sequence([
           SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
           SKAction.run {
               mynode.removeFromParent()
           }
        ]))
```

this method has the advantage that you dont have to check or even care about the time